# How to train large dataset on tensorflow 2.x

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.x

I have a large dataset with about 2M rows and 6,000 columns. The input numpy array (X, y) can hold the training data okay. But when it goes to model.fit(), I get a GPU Out-Of-Memory error. I am using tensorflow 2.2. According to its manual, model.fit_generator has been deprecated and model.fit is preferred.

Can someone outline the steps for training large datasets with tensorflow v2.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution is to use `tf.data.Dataset()` and thus you can easily batch your data with the `.batch()` method.

There are plenty of tutorials available here, you may want to use `from_tensor_slices()` for playing directly with `numpy` arrays.

Below there are two excellent documentations to suit your needs.

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/numpy

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. So in my example, I can set the shuffle_buffer_size = 2,000,000 and then batch_size=200,000, if I want to train 200,000 rows at a time?

Comment: Yes, this it how it would work. Of course, a much lower value for batch_size is feasible, such as 32, 64 etc. Now, it can take a lot of time to shuffle_buffer_size = 2,000,000, you can select a smaller value.

Comment: Thanks, Calin. If I understand the documentation correctly, there are two batch_sizes involved here. Please let me know if I am correct. There is the orignal batch_size that is used to select the number of rows in a mini batch gradient computation. 32 is a good number to use. Then there is another batch_size associated with the Dataset. This is the one that determines the number of rows selected in the TF memory at a time. This batch_size can be as large as the GPU memory can accommodate. Is this correct?

Comment: You do not need to pass the batch_size parameter in model.fit() in this case. It will automatically use the BATCH_SIZE that you use in tf.data.Dataset().batch().

As for your other question : the batch size hyperparameter indeed needs to be carefully tuned. On the other hand, if you see OOM errors, you should decrease it until you do not get OOM (normally in this manner 32 --> 16 --> 8 ...).

In your case I would start with a batch_size of 2 an increase it by a power of two and check if I still get OOM.